# how to emit multiple events from child to parent component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am tring in this way but it is listening for first one not for second.

**child component**

```
 import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
 @Output() userAdded: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 @Output() userDeleted: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

export class ChildComponent{
allUsers = [];
prop = "the value";

 addUser(){
  this.allUsers.push('john');
  this.userAdded.emit(prop);
 }

 deleteUser(idx) {
  this.allUsers.splice(idx, 1);
  this.userDeleted.emit(idx);
 }
}
```

**parent component**

```
<app-child (userAdded)=onAddUser($event) (userDeleted)=onDeleteUser($event)></app-child>
```

Comment: what do you want to emit? you are currently emitting just 'the value' every time in 'addUser'!

Comment: This looks correct. What do you mean the second one doesn't work? what second one and what part isn't working

Comment: the id in the second event emitter i waht to emit and get the value in parent component

Answer (score 0):

```
Parent Component  
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  onAddUser(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

  onDeleteUser(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Please follow the link:
[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpg8lk?file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts)